# Spring form submission and successView problem?

Tags: spring-mvc

(A silly question?)In springframework, the simpleFormController interface has a property called successView, but I am wondering how can I pass the submitted form information to this successView?
The official tutorial has this:

```
return ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
```

Of course, I can add another mapping from this "successView", for example, "result.htm" to another controller, but how would the controller get form information which is useful to render the final view?

*I think it would be also a bad idea to append strings to the getSuccessView()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a redirect for the success view, then you either need to add URL parameters to the redirect URI, or you need to put the data into the session, so that you can retrieve it when the redirected request arrives.  If you don't want to do either of those things, then don't use a redirect.

Incidentally, `SimpleFormController` is obsolete, you shouldn't really be using it, especially if you're just learning Spring. Are you using an old version of the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I am learning spring-framework-2.5.6, could you give me a little advice for learning Spring in a better way. I used spring for one of my class project, it was simple and all I needed was SimpleFormController.

Comment: @baboonWorksFine: If you're just learning Spring now, then learn 3.0, not 2.5.